PowerCLI - Get storage information for VMs on Cloud server
I'm already retrieving some storage information for my VMs with this script:
#Connection to Cloud servers

Connect-CIServer -Server $CloudServer -Org $MyORg -User $user -Password $password
# Get all virtual machines
$vms = MyVM

$hardware = $vm.ExtensionData.GetVirtualHardwareSection()
$diskMB = (($hardware.Item | where {$_.resourcetype.value -eq "17"}) | %{$_.hostresource[0].anyattr[3]."#text"} | Measure-Object -Sum).sum
STORAGE = [math]::ceiling($($diskMB/1024));

But our Datacenter host has different results. It tells us that it also takes into account snapshots and swap.
But I can't find the possibility to have this information in the different commands available.
I can do it without problem for another infrastructure but this time I connect with this script:
Connect-VIServer –Server $MyOtherVCener -User $user -Password $Password

# Get all virtual machines
$vms_cit = My_VM
Storage = [math]::ceiling($($vm_cit.ProvisionedSpaceGB));

This is far more simple.
Is there a command equivalent to ".ProvisionedSpaceGB" but for Cloud Server, or is there a way to get the same result?
